# Setup problem VS .NET 2005 - Can I commit?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

After I created setup in .NET 2005 (.NET Framework 2.0) and tried to install in windows with Service Pack 3 which has .NET framework 2.0 Service pack 1, .NET framework 3.0. It prompted me "Can I commit?" at the end of installation.

And It failed at the end with error code 29527

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Why does anyone think this belongs on serverfault?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the latest updates for VS .NET 2003?  It could be a bug that's been fixed as of one of the service packs or updates to VS itself.

Comment: to make the matter complicated. it was working when i tried to install in another pc that has almost the same configuration. and later i found out i couldnt even install mysql sever 5.1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Visual Studio Package tool you need to change. I never use the standard Visual Studio packaging wizard cause it's too clunky. It runs slow, and it's buggy.

I've been using [Innosetup](http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php) for creating setups since 2004 and it has served me very well. Even with .Net 3.5 it can detect whether it is installed and install it if it is not. In fact I wrote a [small routine](http://cyrilgupta.com/?p=214) to reliably detect 3.5 (which Installshield wasn't doing) with Innosetup.

I seriously recommend u upgrade to a better installer that the standard tool.